# UIScrollView that can scroll, but not from user interaction

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to have a scrollview that has 2 views on it. Both views fill up the screen, and when you push a button on one view it uses scrollRectToVisible to move to the other view.

I want the user to not be able to scroll it with their touch though, so disabling scrolling doesn't work. Obviously i could have scroll become re-enabled when the user touches the button than lock it again afterwards, but then the user could grab or interact while it's unlocked in the scroll animation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops. As it turns out, against some/lots of logic, you can actually disable scroll on the scrollview, but scrollRectToVisible still works, it'll only stop it working if you disable user interaction - i'me guessing because the view with the button inherits from the scollview, so the button wasn't actually working at all.